# How to assign an IF statement inside a map function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign an IF statement inside a map function but it asks for a return. If I put the return, in front of the IF, does not work. Currently getting the following error on Lint: *Line 78:52:  Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function  array-callback-return*

I expect just to push objects into the array.

What is the correct way to assign the IF inside a map?

```
     { ingredientIndex.map((currentIndex) => {
        const ingredient = detail[`strIngredient${currentIndex}`];
        const measure = detail[`strMeasure${currentIndex}`];
        if (ingredient) {
          validIngredients.push(`${ingredient} - ${measure}`);
        }
      }) }
```

Comment: `if` is a statement in javascript, not an expression

Comment: Sorry @DanielA.White I am newbie, please explain.

Comment: use a `forEach` instead since you are looking for a side effect, not actually doing a map.  `map` is not a general replacement for iterators

Comment: it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here. If you're not trying to return a new array, you should use `forEach` instead of `map`. I also note the `{...}` around this - is this react JS? If so then you definitely shouldn't be anything like this inside rendered (JSX) output - but I don't know what you should do instead because the question is lacking context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ingredientIndex.forEach(currentIndex => {
                ^^^^^^^
```